# Intermittent failure of container mounts in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are seeing an intermittent failure of volume mount with this error message:

> Error: cannot find volume "work" to mount into container "notebook".

The issue happens on ~5% of pod launches (where they all have the same config). The volume is backed by PVC which is created immediately before pod creation.

We are running on GKE with version `v1.11.7-gke.12`.

Pod **manifest** is here:

```
{
      apiVersion: 'v1',
      kind: 'Pod',
      metadata: {
        name: 'some pod name',
        annotations: {},
        labels: {},
      },
      spec: {
        restartPolicy: 'OnFailure',
        securityContext: {
          fsGroup: 100,
        },
        automountServiceAccountToken: false,
        volumes: [
          {
            name: 'work',
            persistentVolumeClaim: {
              claimName: pvcName,
            },
          },
        ],
        containers: [
          {
            name: 'notebook',
            image,
            workingDir: undefined, // this is defined in Dockerfile
            ports: [
              {
                name: 'notebook-port',
                containerPort: port,
              },
            ],
            args: [...command.split(' '), ...args],
            imagePullPolicy: 'IfNotPresent',
            volumeMounts: [
              {
                name: 'work',
                mountPath: '/home/jovyan/work',
              },
            ],
            resources: {
              requests: {
                memory: '256M',
              },
              limits: {
                memory: '1G',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            name: 'watcher',
            image: 'gcr.io/deepnote-200602/wacher:0.0.3',
            imagePullPolicy: 'Always',
            volumeMounts: [
              {
                name: 'work',
                mountPath: '/home/jovyan/work',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  }
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Also, very happy to try any  suggestions what other logs/steps might be useful to isolate the issue.

Comment: A seemingly related question on SO is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114457/intermittent-failure-creating-container-on-kubernetes-failing-to-mount-default but there is no answer nor hints how to proceed apart from version change, which we can't do since we are on GKE.

Comment: Documentation states "Mount options are not validated, so mount will simply fail if one is invalid." Do you use manifest files or do you use kubectl create command to create the cluster? You provided the pod spec but the pv spec is not mentioned. The doc at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#claims-as-volumes discusses the many possibilities of errors that can happen with PV's. You need to find the PV configuration for your system.

Comment: Can you check `PV` & `PVC` status/`describe` output and also manifests for them.

Answer (score 0):

most likely the volume is not bound. can you check and confirm status of below pvc

claimName: pvcName

```
kubectl get pvc | grep pvcName
```